# Can i authenticate to Azure Devops while running a python script without a user?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am writing a python script to create a user in Azure DevOps. 
For that first, I need to authenticate with Azure DevOps.

These are my concerns:

1) I used Azure DevOps python client API (which is much simpler than raw REST API calls) to access Azure DevOps. But the authentication was done using a personal access token (PAT). This method was successful.

2) But I don't want to use a PAT which is different for each user. I need a more generalized script. For example, we authenticate to Microsoft GRAPH API **without a user (not as a particular user, but as the application itself)**. That method uses a registered AAD app ID and client secret.

3) I can use ADAL client Library to simplify that authentication process with Graph API. So, is that possible to user ADAL to authenticate to Azure DevOps services?

4) Is it possible to authenticate to Azure DevOps with that AAD app(that means not as a specific user)? Or should I create a new app for Azure DevOps services?

5) If authentication with AAD app is possible, then can I use Python client API to perform the operations like list projects, create user, etc? If yes, how? Or should I perform these operations with raw REST API calls?

Comment: You are actually asking too many questions in this one question. Please separate your questions or be specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Azure AD token to authenticate with Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52896114/use-azure-ad-token-to-authenticate-with-azure-devops)